# Непонятная конструкция в Си

Tags: c

Недавно добрался до книжки по Си Б.Кернигана и Д.Ритчи.
Не могу понять, что значит:

```
s[i] - '0'
```

При условии что:
`s` - массив char
`i` - переменная-счётчик в циле
В тексте объяснения не нашёл.

Comment: В си кодить - это радость :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Си тип `char` является числовым к нему можно также прибавлять и отнимать числа.

```
s[i] - '0'
```

в указанном куске кода автор использует трюк для перевода символа-цифры в число. Т.к. в кодировке символов цифры идут подряд начиная с `0`, то если в `s[i]` содержится цифра, тогда результатом вычитания будет та же цифра, только уже в численном виде, а не в символьном.

Код символа `0` это `48`, код символа `7` будет `55`. Соответственно `55 - 48` будет `7`.

Comment: Спасибо. Есть над чем подумать.

Comment: @Vladimir выражение будет работать, даже если кодом символа 0 будет не 48 (напр. EBCDIC). Лишь бы коды шли подряд.

Answer (score 7):

> В тексте объяснения не нашёл.

Честно-честно? :)

> Как мы уже говорили в главе 1, выражение s[i] - '0' дает числовое значение символа, хранящегося в s[i], так как значения '0' , '1' и пр. образуют непрерывную возрастающую последовательность.

Comment: Вот что бывает, когда читаешь по одной главе в месяц :(